# (Ubuntu Server 11.04) Proftpd permission denied with USB HDDs

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, usb, ftp

I have an external HDD mounted in my server. It's on /dev/sdb1 (or /media/usb0). I have a proftpd user which home directory is set to /media/usb0.

The problem is that the ownership of /media/usb0 is root, and I cannot change that. I always get permission denied when trying to upload a file.

I already tried setting chmod -R 777 /media/usb0/ but it does not work too.

The proftpd linux user is proftpd.

How do I set the right permissions to the usb hdd?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that your USB device is using FAT as the filesystem?  FAT does not support *nix style permissions.  There is no concept of ownership or permissions, and so you are not permitted to use chmod/chmod on the folder.

When you mount a FAT filesystem under Linux you can pass a few options to set the UID/GID/Dmask, and Fmask.

See [man mount](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount)

```
uid=value and gid=value
  Set the owner and group of all files. (Default: the uid and 
  gid of the current process.)
dmask=value
  Set the umask applied to directories only. The default is the 
  umask of the current process. The value is given in octal.
fmask=value
  Set the umask applied to regular files only. The default is 
  the umask of the current process. The value is given in octal.
```

Comment: My fstab:
/dev/sdb1    /home/usbstorage0    auto    noauto,uid=proftpd,fmask=022,dmask=022    0   0
and I still getting permission denied...
Any idea?

Comment: If login as that user via SSH or on the local system, is that user able to write to the fielsystem?